# Updating/interrupting a stdin.read_line prompt with output

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I'm creating a command line terminal/parser that displays a prompt and takes commands from the user. I do this with a simple:

```rust
'prompt: loop{
    # display prompt, stdin.read_line, and execute commands based on input...
}
```

What I'd like to do is have the ability to output text based on some trigger (timer or otherwise) that will "interrupt" the prompt but then immediately go back to accepting stdin. It might look something like this:

```
[11:39:00] Enter your command:
Alert! AAPL has decreased by greater than 5%
[11:40:00] Enter your command:
```

Basically, the loop needs to keep running and checking for events, while also accepting user input.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: That doesn't look like ideal UX to me — especially if you're mirroring `stdin` as the user types in order to give feedback: it would result in duplicated lines with partial input. IMO, it would be a nicer pattern to delete existing lines that your program has already written, and then rewrite the desired output.

Comment: I agree the UX is not ideal, but it's what I've chosen to go with. It's a personal project for my own uses and for getting my hands dirty with rust.